# How to learn SOAP and Web Services?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm supposed to take this at-home skills test for a potential employer. They threw me a curveball, asking me to build a page that consumes their ASP.NET API.

I have access to the API documentation, and instructions for what information my page need to be able to pull.

I've got some PHP skills, and some understanding of AJAX, so I'm assuming I start there.  But that's all I know!  Where should I start?

Comment: With respect, if you don't know how to do this, why not tell the truth and say that you don't?

Comment: besides :)   I'd rather just figure it out than throw my hands up.   And happily I can report, at 6 in the morning without sleeping, that I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.  As mentioned - there is a long way to go with this.  Are they using SOAP based web services?  REST?   You may start here;  http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php  Just making an assumption that you will get access to a WSDL but no guarantee.  If the web services are REST based look at the how Yahoo recommends handling them (http://developer.yahoo.com/php/howto-parseRestPhp.html) Or maybe look at a REST library like Tonic (http://peej.github.com/tonic/). Or even this IBM article on how to handle Google REST-based feeds: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-gbookapi/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: sorry to come back 5 months later.   I got the job! :)